# PhD Applications and GRE Subject Tests during Covid

Tags: phd, mathematics, gre

I just recently finished a masters program in Mathematics, unfortunately it seems most PhD Programs require a math GRE Subject test. At the moment I'm living with my parents and don't feel comfortable going in to take an exam with others - especially with the cases in the US right now, but I don't want to lose a shot at getting into some programs.

Does anyone know if universities have lifted the requirement for GRE Subject tests as a result of Covid?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Certainly if universities want students in a time of chaos, they need to be somewhat flexible in their admissions. Some will have dropped the GRE requirement, and some haven't had it for a while.

Unfortunately that is an individual decision by an individual university (or perhaps a statewide system) in the US, so you have to inquire for each university to learn a useful answer. Don't assume that any given university has, or hasn't, made changes to their requirements.

However, note that ETS is making accommodations also. It is possible to take the [General Test at home](https://www.ets.org/s/cv/gre/at-home/) under certain circumstances. It doesn't seem to include the Subject tests, though that may change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately the test at home option is for the General Test, not the Subject Tests, though I'm surprised they don't offer that. (Ah correction, I see now you edited!)

Comment: @GastonGonzalez: There is a reason that test at home is available for General but not Subject.  For the general, they have enough test takers to be able to collect lots of data to statistically calibrate the difficulty of many different versions of the test.  For any particular subject test, they have a lot less data and hence they are only able to calibrate one or two versions at a time, so if they do test at home, the test will be leaked and there will be widespread cheating.

Answer (score 1):

Some universities are not requiring GRE test this year due to the pandemic, see for example UChicago's website - https://mathematics.uchicago.edu/academics/graduate-programs/mathematics-phd-program/how-to-apply/

On the other hand, I know 10-14 days quarantining alone in a motel, after taking the test, might be depressing, but it seems that's one possible solution for your situation.
If you know some other friends taking the GRE, you can do that together and actually enjoy this time.

Comment: It seems Princeton is also GRE optional - https://www.math.princeton.edu/graduate/admissions , same with MIT - https://math.mit.edu/academics/grad/admission/index.php, CAL - https://math.berkeley.edu/programs/graduate/admissions , Stanford - https://mathematics.stanford.edu/academicsgraduate-students/graduate-admissions . I suspect Harvard is doing/will do the same. So probably if you are just applying to top-6, you should be OK.

Nevertheless, it is always smart to cast a wide net in your applications, especially giving the current pandemic and academia/job market effects.